# create an array of objects with coordinates in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I have an object like this

```
class Place
  def initialize(x,y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end
end
```

So, I have to emulate a dynamic `grid` with size X,Y. For example 3x5 (`width`, `height`).

I need to save all the "Place" objects in the array, with all the possible values, Place(1,1), Place(1,2), Place(1,3)... Place(3,5).

I tried this way (inside `Grid`)

```
def createPlaces width, height
    @places = Array.new(width * height)

    (0..width).to_a.each do |x|
      (0..height).to_a.each do |y|
        @places.push(Place.new(x,y))
      end
    end
  end
```

But is not working. How can I do it?

Comment: One Ruby convention is to use [snake-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for names of variables and methods. You don't have to conform, but 99%+ of Rubiests do.

Comment: You might mean `0...width`, where that is equivalent to `0..width-1`. Width 10 would mean 11 entries in your array with your code, which is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@places = (0...width).to_a.product((0...height).to_a).map do |x, y|
  Place.new(x,y)
end
```

Thanks @tadman, there are to be triple-dotted ranges to exclude the tight borders from ranges (`[0, width)`). That makes an amount of elements exactly equal `width` and `height`.

Comment: `..` vs `...` here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
@places = Array.new(width * height)
```

to

```
@places = Array.new
```

`Array#push` creates a new element at the end of array, since you already created an array with certain number of elements, and then pushing more elements into it - you may be observing first `width * height` elements to be `nil`